# Cast to type dynamically from string name of type

Tags: .net, dynamic, types

So I'm making a game maker editor where coders will be able to make a DLL that has a class in it that is derived from a specific base class (let's say Behavior). They put their DLL's in a plugin folder and the main game maker exe loads all these DLL's.

Their class can have properties that when they assign an instance of it to a game object they can set the initial values of the properties. This is all done from a grid and using reflection to inspect the properties of the class.

This of course has to be saved to a file at some point to be reloaded when they want to reopen the game maker project or run the game. Ideally the main exe would be able to read in this data and cast the values saved to the correct property type.

I also don't want to ask the programmers of these DLL's to use dynamic for each type. So would this be possible?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add an interface to Serialize / Deserialize the data into whatever... json, xml, binary and persist them somewhere?

Comment: This would require the programmers of the DLL's to handle this for their type right? I was just trying to make it easier on them by having the main exe handle it all. Basically all they would need to know is that any public property they expose will be able to have it's value modified by the user and it'll be saved to/from disk without them having to do anything. Ideally.

Comment: Was able to get it working for properties:
<code>
string propName = "WalkSpeed";
            string propValue = "5.5";

            Type t = typeof(Controller);
            Behavior b = (Behavior)Activator.CreateInstance(t);

            PropertyInfo prop = t.GetProperty(propName);
            string type = prop.PropertyType.ToString();

            prop.SetValue(b, Convert.ChangeType(propValue, Type.GetType(type)), null);
</code>